# Unable to import fasttext library in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed the fasttext library in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine at the python3 packages folder but I am unable to import it.

```
>>> import fasttext

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rahul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fasttext/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .fasttext import skipgram
  File "fasttext/fasttext.pyx", line 13, in init fasttext.fasttext
ImportError: No module named 'model'
```

Ideally, it should not give any errors after importing.

Comment: how did you install it? did you use pip3 or pip. python3 is not the default python. Are you in the right interpreter?

Comment: I installed fasttext using pip3. And trying to import it in the terminal like this.



_Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)_
_[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux_
_Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information._
**>>> import fasttext**

Comment: I installed it following the pip method here https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python and it works. Check these versions of dependances (gcc-4.8 or newer) or (clang-3.3 or newer). Ubuntu 16.04 is not a recent distrib.